# jinja : using variable from for loop inside an if statement

Tags: loops, if-statement, jinja2

I am trying to use a variable in a "if" statement, this variable is defined in a for loop, but I cannot get it to work, here is the code excerpt:

```
{% for dir in ['temp','backup','sbin','logs','apps'] %}
  {% if {{ dir }} == 'temp' %}
    /tree/{{ dir }}:
      file.directory:
      - user: user1
      - group: user1
      - mode: 1777
      - makedirs: True
  {% endif %}
  /tree/{{ dir }}:
    file.directory:
      - user: root
      - group: root
      - mode: 755
      - makedirs: True
{% endfor %}
```

I think the code is self explanatory, if not please ask!

I know my code is not the best looking one, if you have any advice,
I'd be happy to take them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `{% if dir == 'temp' %}` would be correct.

EDIT: Typo fixed :)

Comment: your answer seems to be working (minus the typo around your 'temp' :) ), although I tried this before without luck .... thank you.